# Label wrap in D3 sunburst chart

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

```js
import { text } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";

// https://observablehq.com/@jccuartas31/zoomable-sunburst/2@379
export default function define(runtime, observer) {
    const main = runtime.module();
    const fileAttachments = new Map([["flare-1.json","/flare-1.json"]]);
    //const fileAttachments = new Map([["flare@1.json",new URL("./files/1d04637f576319778c1730327216dc92142b89de46fc8192578c711ef8d68bcefa5f430bda06ca978c99f794f9f58b0cd1fa22bb19dd298f63d76751ca5149fe",import.meta.url)]]);
    main.builtin("FileAttachment", runtime.fileAttachments(name => fileAttachments.get(name)));
    main.variable(observer()).define(["md"], function(md){return(
  md`# Zoomable Sunburst
  
  This variant of a [sunburst diagram](/@d3/sunburst) shows only two layers of the hierarchy at a time. Click a node to zoom in, or the center to zoom out. Compare to an [icicle](/@d3/zoomable-icicle).`
  )});
    main.variable(observer("chart")).define("chart", ["partition","data","d3","DOM","width","color","arc","format","radius"], function(partition,data,d3,DOM,width,color,arc,format,radius)
  {
    const root = partition(data);
  
    root.each(d => d.current = d);
  
    const svg = d3.select(DOM.svg(width, width))
        .style("width", "80%")
        .style("height", "auto")
        .style("font", "70px sans-serif")
        //.style("word-wrap", "break-word")
        //.style("background-color","red")
        //.attr("x", 20)
        //.attr("y", 20)
       // .call(wrap, 60);
  
    const g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2},${width / 2})`)
        
  
    const path = g.append("g")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
      .join("path")
        .attr("fill", d => { while (d.depth > 1) d = d.parent; return color(d.data.name); })
        .attr("fill-opacity", d => arcVisible(d.current) ? (d.children ? 0.6 : 0.4) : 0)
        .attr("d", d => arc(d.current))
        .on("mouseover", function(d){
            if(!d.children){return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible").text(d.data.name).style("display",                 "block");}
          })
          .on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top",
        (d3.event.pageY-40)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX+20)+"px");})
          .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");})
          .call(wrap, 60);
  
    path.filter(d => d.children)
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .on("click", clicked);
  
    //path.append("title")
        //.text(d => `${d.ancestors().map(d => d.data.name).reverse().join("/")}\n${format(d.value)}`);
  
    const label = g.append("g")
          
        .attr("pointer-events", "none")
        .attr("class", "wrap")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("user-select", "none")
      .selectAll("text")
      
      
      
      .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
      .join("text")
        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
        
       // .attr("dx", "5")
      
        .attr("fill-opacity", d => +labelVisible(d.current))
        .attr("transform", d => labelTransform(d.current))
        //.text(d => d.data.name);
        .text(d => d.data.name != undefined && d.data.name.length < 30 ? d.data.name : d.data.short)
        
  
    const parent = g.append("circle")
        .datum(root)
        .attr("r", radius)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("pointer-events", "all")
        .on("click", clicked);

        const tooltip = d3.select("body")
        .append("div")
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("z-index", "10")
        .style("visibility", "hidden")
        .style("background-color", "black") 
        .style("opacity", 0.5)
        .style("color", "white")
        .style("font-size", "12px")
        .style("padding", "15px")
        .style("width", "300px")
        .style("display", "none")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .text("")
        
  
    function clicked(p) {
      parent.datum(p.parent || root);
  
      root.each(d => d.target = {
        x0: Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (d.x0 - p.x0) / (p.x1 - p.x0))) * 2 * Math.PI,
        x1: Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (d.x1 - p.x0) / (p.x1 - p.x0))) * 2 * Math.PI,
        y0: Math.max(0, d.y0 - p.depth),
        y1: Math.max(0, d.y1 - p.depth)
      });
  
      const t = g.transition().duration(750);
  
      // Transition the data on all arcs, even the ones that aren’t visible,
      // so that if this transition is interrupted, entering arcs will start
      // the next transition from the desired position.
      path.transition(t)
          .tween("data", d => {
            const i = d3.interpolate(d.current, d.target);
            return t => d.current = i(t);
            
          })
        .filter(function(d) {
          return +this.getAttribute("fill-opacity") || arcVisible(d.target);
        })
          .attr("fill-opacity", d => arcVisible(d.target) ? (d.children ? 0.6 : 0.4) : 0)
          .attrTween("d", d => () => arc(d.current));
  
      label.filter(function(d) {
          return +this.getAttribute("fill-opacity") || labelVisible(d.target);
        }).transition(t)
          .attr("fill-opacity", d => +labelVisible(d.target))
          .attrTween("transform", d => () => labelTransform(d.current));
    }
    
    function arcVisible(d) {
      return d.y1 <= 3 && d.y0 >= 1 && d.x1 > d.x0;
    }
  
    function labelVisible(d) {
      return d.y1 <= 3 && d.y0 >= 1 && (d.y1 - d.y0) * (d.x1 - d.x0) > 0.03;
    }
  
    function labelTransform(d) {
      const x = (d.x0 + d.x1) / 2 * 180 / Math.PI;
      const y = (d.y0 + d.y1) / 2 * radius;
      return `rotate(${x - 90}) translate(${y},0) rotate(${x < 180 ? 0 : 180})`;
    }
    
    function wrap(text, width) {
        console.log({text, width})
      text.each(function () {
          var text = d3.select(this),
              words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
              word,
              line = [],
              lineNumber = 0,
              lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
              x = text.attr("x"),
              y = text.attr("y"),
              dy = 0, //parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
              tspan = text.text(null)
                          .append("tspan")
                          .attr("x", x)
                          .attr("y", y)
                          .attr("dy", dy + "em");
          while (word = words.pop()) {
              line.push(word);
              tspan.text(line.join(" "));
              if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                  line.pop();
                  tspan.label(line.join(" "));
                  line = [word];
                  tspan = text.label("tspan")
                              .attr("x", x)
                              .attr("y", y)
                              .attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em")
                              .text(word);
              }
          }
      });
  }
    
    return svg.node();
  }
  );
  main.variable(observer("data")).define("data", ["FileAttachment"], function(FileAttachment){return(
    FileAttachment("flare-1.json").json()
    )});
    main.variable(observer("partition")).define("partition", ["d3"], function(d3){return(
  data => {
    const root = d3.hierarchy(data)
        .sum(d => d.value)
        .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);
    return d3.partition()
        .size([2 * Math.PI, root.height + 1])
      (root);
  }
  )});
    main.variable(observer("color")).define("color", ["d3","data"], function(d3,data){return(
  d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.quantize(d3.interpolateRainbow, data.children.length + 1))
  )});
    main.variable(observer("format")).define("format", ["d3"], function(d3){return(
  d3.format(",d")
  )});
    main.variable(observer("width")).define("width", function(){return(
  5000
  )});
    main.variable(observer("radius")).define("radius", ["width"], function(width){return(
  width / 6
  )});
    main.variable(observer("arc")).define("arc", ["d3","radius"], function(d3,radius){return(
  d3.arc()
      .startAngle(d => d.x0)
      .endAngle(d => d.x1)
      .padAngle(d => Math.min((d.x1 - d.x0) / 2, 0.005))
      .padRadius(radius * 1.5)
      .innerRadius(d => d.y0 * radius)
      .outerRadius(d => Math.max(d.y0 * radius, d.y1 * radius - 1))
  )});
    main.variable(observer("d3")).define("d3", ["require"], function(require){return(
  require("d3@5")
  )});
    return main;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I am tryin to add label to D3 sunburst chart :https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-sunburst.
I am integrating it in React WebApp.
But I am facing issue with long label.
I tried the Text wrap function by Mike ,but it is not working.
Below is the code is am using. I am struck at the wrap part. Kindly please help in resolving the issue.

Comment: you forgot to add the code you mention in the question

Comment: I am trying to add code but not able to add it.

Comment: can i share the details with you over email. I am sorry but I am not getting any other way and I need help on this issue urgently.

Comment: Please create some codepen or codesandbox with your code. You can use markdown to paste code in your questiin

Comment: I have added the code .It same as from observeablehq.com. Just have added the wrap function, which is not working. The long label are not getting split .Could you please help

Comment: as much as we all'd like to help you, without a clear statement of what you want to achieve and where did you stuck within **your** code, we can't help you. The code you sent has syntax errors and it is just a copy-paste from the observable which uses own syntax and will not work 'out of the box', it is not helpful. I suggest to create a minimum example of your own implementation, ie. on codepen, and then relate specifically to what problem you have in the code .Before that check stackoverflow - there are answers about wrapping svg <text> as well as adding ellipsis if text is too long.